# Let the user enter start and end times and split the duration into equal divisions

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to write a program that allows the user to enter in a start time hour, end time hour, and number of divisions.

So they might enter 9, 10, and 4 which should mean a start time of 9:00AM, end of 10:00AM and to split the range 4 times, resulting in an output of 9:00, 9:15, 9:30, 9:45.

I've tried using the time module and datetime, but cannot get the addition of time to work. I do not care about date.

I can calculate the time split, but the actual addition to the start time is evading me.

I have a hodge-podge of code, and the following is mostly me experimenting trying to figure out how to make this work. I've tried adding the minutes, tried converting to seconds, delved into datetime, tried the time module, but can't seem to get it to work. There are plenty of examples of how to "add 15 minutes to now" but the issue is I don't want to start at the "now", but rather let the user decide start time.

```
time_start = "9"
time_end = "10"
time_split = "4"


if len(time_start) == 1:
   time_start =  "0" + str(time_start) + ":00"
else:
   time_start =   str(time_start) + ":00"

if len(time_end) == 1:
   time_end =  "0" + str(time_end) + ":00"
else:
   time_end =   str(time_end) + ":00"

print time_start
print time_end

s1 = time_start + ':00'
s2 = time_end + ':00'
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
divided = tdelta / int(time_split)

print tdelta
print divided
s3 = str(divided)
print "s1 time start: " + str(s1)
print "s2 time end: " + str(s2)
print "s3 time divided: " + str(s3)
ftr = [3600,60,1]
add_seconds =  sum([a*b for a,b in zip(ftr, map(int,s3.split(':')))])
print "s3 time divided seconds: " + str(add_seconds)
print "time delta: " + str(tdelta)
```

Comment: You'll have to answer some key questions first: how do you handle splitting a day (e.g. 10pm - 2am)? 12- or 24-hour format (e.g. 10 = 10:00am or 10:00pm)?

Comment: Also, how do you plan to handle input such as 9, 10, and 7. where splitting isn't as simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that elegantly handles resolution to the millisecond:

```
import datetime

start_time = 9 # per user input
end_time = 10 # per user input
divisions = 7 # per user input

total_time = end_time - start_time
start_time = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),datetime.time(start_time))
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=total_time)

increment = total_time*3600000//divisions # resolution in ms

times = [(start_time+datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=increment*i)).time()
         for i in range(divisions)]

from pprint import pprint

pprint(list(map(str,times)))

# ['09:00:00',
#  '09:08:34.285000',
#  '09:17:08.570000',
#  '09:25:42.855000',
#  '09:34:17.140000',
#  '09:42:51.425000',
#  '09:51:25.710000']
```

Comment: Note that since you requested an even split, "minutes" is the finest resolution this code will implement. As @Jordonias mentioned in a comment on your question, if you want to split 8 times (7.5 minutes each), this code won't exactly FAIL, but it won't be correct.